# Changing a SF clusters default RDP ports

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I've created a SF cluster from the Azure portal and by default it uses incrementing ports starting at 3389 for RDP access to the VMs. How can I change this to another range?

Additionally, or even alternatively, is there a way to specify the range when I create a cluster?

I realize this may not be so much of a SF question as a Load Balanacer or Scale Set question, but I ask in the context of SF because that is how I created this setup. IOW I did not create the load balancer or scale set myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change this with an ARM template (Azure Resource Manager).

Since you will run into situations from time to time where you want to change parts of your infrastructure, I'd recommend to create the whole cluster from an ARM template instead of through the portal. By doing so you could also create the cluster in an existing VNET, use internal load balancers, etc.

To create the cluster from an ARM template, you can either start with the [Azure Quickstart template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/service-fabric-secure-cluster-5-node-1-nodetype-wad) or by clicking on "Export template" in the Azure Portal right before you would actually create the cluster.

To change the inbound NAT rules for RDP in the template, change the section [`inboundNatPools`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/service-fabric-secure-cluster-5-node-1-nodetype-wad/azuredeploy.json#L387) in the template.

If you want to change your existing cluster, you can either [export your existing resource group](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/export-template/) as a template or you can try to create a template which contains just the loadBalancer-resource and re-deploy just this part.

Working with ARM templates needs some getting used to, but it has many advantages. It allows you to easily change settings that can not be configured through the portal, it allows you to easily re-create the cluster for different environments, etc.